# Why a method call in OnStateEnter and OnStateExit do not invoke in the correct order?

Tags: unity, animation, fsm, animation-states, statemachine

[image: My Animator Controller]

I have a class that extends from `StateMachineBehaviour`. All I want to do is invoke some code in a specific state's first frame and the last frame to trigger some action in the game. But method calls in `OnStateEnter` and `OnStateExit` invoke inaccurately like below. And I saw a couple of articles in the Unity forum about how inaccurate `StateMachineBehaviour` works. Is there something I should pay attention to or any suggestion on how to invoke some code in the specific frame?

[Here is the code](https://gist.github.com/yektasarioglu/505c00f905132ac7302f5c623aa4ada2)

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe the specific symptoms of "inaccurate invocation" you're observing?

Comment: I added some resources to clarify things. I hope that is enough. @DMGregory

Comment: So if I understand your log correctly, your problem is that the finished-event fires before the started-event?

Comment: Yes, @Philipp. That's the exact problem.

Comment: This is a wild guess but maybe it is related to your transitions between states. If I remember correctly animator is very "responsive", i.e. it can pass through states in one itteration. Try to make sure that transitions are setup in a way that some time is spent in each state.